# Maximizing minimal distance between consecutive brushstrokes when painting a checkerboard torus

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, applications

Suppose you have a 2-torus and you want to paint an $m\times n$ checkerboard pattern on it.
Every brushstroke could paint a single square. 
How does one maximize the minimal distance between consecutive brushstrokes? You can assume $m=n$ if that helps.

---

Here's the background of the problem. The next generation of eBeam machines that print reticles for semiconductor
manufacturing is "painting" the reticle with a grid of parallel electron beams, the beams being a certain distance
$\Delta$ from each other. Each beam exposes a pixel of size $\delta << \Delta$. The checkerboard mentioned above
has side $n = \Delta / \delta$.

After each exposure the grid of beams advances by a small amount and paints more pixels between those that already
have been exposed. One needs to perform $n^2$ exposured to complete the reticle in this interleaving manner.

Now, how fast can consecutive exposures be performed? That depends, among other things, on how close their positions
are modulo $n$. The heat absorbed by a pixel from a previous exposure may affect the sensitivity 
of the pixel in the next exposure if the pixels are too close too each other. Therefore one needs to schedule the
$n^2$ exposures in such manner so that the minimal distance between consecutive exposure positions modulo $n$ would be maximized.

Which is obviously equivalent to the question above.

Comment: How are you defining distance?

Comment: Two questions: (1) When you said checkerboard, I originally took you to mean just the black squares. But I think I was misreading and I am supposed to paint all $n^2$ squares of the $n \times n$ grid, is that right? (2) Is it really enough to just maximize the distance between consecutive strokes? As I understand the application, it seems like it might also be important to get stroke $k$ far from stroke $k+2$, and in general far from $k+r$ for $r$ small.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, you are right, for the application $k+r$ distance for small $r$ would also matter. The effect decays exponentially in $r$ due to heat dissipation. From math point of view, I think the case with $r=1$ is interesting enough for arbitrary $n$, and cleaner to formulate, therefore I stated the MO question as I did.

Answer (score 5):

I asked some questions above about my understanding of the model. If I understand it correctly, I propose we choose the grid to be $(2p) \times (2p+1)$ where $p$ and $2p+1$ are both prime. (Such a $p$ is called a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) and there are conjectured to be infinitely many of them.) Then paint at the multiples of $(p-2, p)$, wrapping around modulo $(2p) \mathbb{Z} \times (2p+1) \mathbb{Z}$. Consecutively painted squares will be $\sqrt{(p-2)^2 + p^2} \approx p \sqrt{2}$ apart and all squares sill be painted eventually. Since $p \sqrt{2}$ is about as far as two points can be in a torus of side length $\approx p$, this is close to optimal.

Note, however, that the squares two brush strokes apart are displaced by only $\sqrt{4^2+1^2}$, which is quite small. That's why I asked above if it is really okay to only focus on consecutive brush strokes.

Answer (score 1):

Following the logic of the previous answer, choose any two primes $p,q$ and let $m=p,n=q.$

The map $$f_{a}:\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$$ defined by $x \mapsto ax$ is a permutation for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ whenever $a\neq 0.$ Similarly for $q$.

For example, let the stroke sequence be the concatenation of the sequences
$$\{(f_{a}(t),f_{b}(t')):0\leq t\leq p-1\},
$$
in the order $t'=0,1,q-1.$ Then any two strokes $k$ time units apart will have distance lower bounded by $k\sqrt{a^2+b^2},$ provided 
$$k\leq \min ( \lfloor p/a \rfloor, \lfloor q/b\rfloor)
.$$